# DB / performance: layout of django model that rarely refers to its parent more than once

Tags: django, performance, schema, django-views

I have an app that's about presenting fictional simplified cities.

Please consider the following Django models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

TYPEGROUP_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'basic'),
    (2, 'extra'),
)

class BldgType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    group = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPEGROUP_CHOICES)

class Building(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    type = models.ForeignKey(BldgType)
    other_criterion = models.ForeignKey(...)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'created_at'
```

Explanations for choosing this setup:

(1) Each city has certain buildings of a "basic" type which occur exactly once per city (examples: city hall, fire station, police station, hospital, school) and possibly dozens of buildings of "extra" type, such as dance clubs.

(2) In certain views, all buildings (regardless of city, etc.) are to be filtered according to different criteria, e.g., `other_criterion`.

**Problem/concern:**

In a `city_detail` view, I would have to loop over any buildings of "extra" type, which is OK and normal.

But I am not sure how to efficiently retrieve the city's "hospital" building, which is of "basic" type, so I must do this for every city anyway because exactly one such hospital exists in each city (this is ensured at city creation time).

There will be at most a dozen of "basic" building types, of which about half will be presented all the time.

I'm inclined towards writing convenience methods on the City model, and I face three options:

(A1) Via `try` and index: `.filter(...)[0]`

(A2) Via `try` and `.get(...)`

(A3) Via `try` and `.filter(...).latest()`

But none of those seem elegant.
Or is one of these three options good to combine with some sort of caching, like in Django's `get_profile()` method on the `User` model? Unfortunately, I have no experience with caching yet.

Is it nuts to use the following option?

(B) specific FKs in the City model, one for each of the most important basic types

**Question:**

Which option makes sense the most?
Or is the schema generally faulty for this kind of scenario?

Especially regarding DB performance, what do you suggest? Do I need a completely different approach?

Please advise! :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a city can have no more than one each of  city hall, fire station, police station, hospital, school etc. then I think the most straightforward way to enforce this is to declare each one as a field on the model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    city_hall = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    fire_station = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    # ... et cetera
```

If you find this too "messy" in your City model, you might consider having an intermediate `CityBuildings` model:

```
class CityBuildings(models.Model):
    city_hall = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    fire_station = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    # ... et cetera

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    buildings = models.OneToOneField(CityBuildings)
```

Then you refer to buildings as, for example, `city.buildings.fire_station`

These are just suggestions... I am not sure if either way is more "correct"

Comment: +1 I agree with this solution - for the record though: It is recommended that you use a `ForeignKey` with a `unique=True` argument instead of a OneToOne =D

Comment: @Jim I don't think it is; that was the advice around 0.96, when there was a long time when 'the semantics of OneToOnes will be changing soon', but there's no reason not to use a OneToOne these days.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer and comments so far, it's really appreciated!
Jim, you are right about my additional worrying about "model messyness". ;) My current problem with the CityBuildings model, however, would be that "nobody else" uses it except for the City model, thus introducing an unnecessary additional JOIN via the OneToOneField, which would take me back to option (B) above, i.e., to the first version of your answer. Any thoughts on the performance issue, i.e., would option (B) still be better than any of the (A) options? Also, again, I'm by far no expert an caching possiblities. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested: silly me discovered the existence of the memoization technique, so I will use some form of that applied to (A2), wrapped in as many convenience methods on the City model as I have "basic" building types.

This is at least somewhat less messy than having FKs in two directions and lets the code be more clear about the separation of interests (modelling on one side, performance on the other).

On the quick, I made out two projects to look at for learning and possibly lending stuff or applying directly:

1. [django-memoize](http://bitbucket.org/lorien/django-memoize/)
2. github.com/husio/django-easycache/

Mayhaps someone will find this useful also.